# var frow = e.rowStart; returning undefined instead of a number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to generate a basic key based on the rowStart of the event from a form submission. I Know that the info is there based on logging `JSON.stringify(e)`.

Example data from `e`:

```
[19-07-30 20:05:54:656 CDT] {"authMode":{},"values":["7/30/2019 20:05:54","1","test","test","myself@someplace.com"],"namedValues":{"some other random stuff here":["test"],"Makin Bacon":["1"],"some random stuff here":["test"],"Timestamp":["7/30/2019 20:05:54"],"Email Address":["myself@someplace.com"]},"range":{"columnStart":1,"rowStart":37,"rowEnd":37,"columnEnd":5},"source":{},"triggerUid":"1234567"}
```

However when I try to get the `rowStart` number from this event by doing `var frow = e.rowStart;` it appears to be undefined in the logger.

Also I get nothing in the logger if I attempt to format the number using `Utilities.formatString("%05d", frow)` but I have tested this on just a number and it works fine.

Can someone explain why I am getting an undefined variable here?

```
function AM2(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var form_name = "Form Responses 1";
  var open_name = "OPEN";

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(form_name);
  var open_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(open_name);

  var frow = e.rowStart;
  var uni_key = "T" + Utilities.formatString("%05d", frow);
  Logger.log(uni_key); // not logging anything.
  var refSheetId = form_ws.getSheetId().toString();

  open_ws.appendRow(['NEW',e.values[1],'','=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/redacted_for_post/edit#gid=' + refSheetId + '&range=D' + frow + '", "' + e.values[2] +'")',e.values[4], uni_key]);

  var rng = open_ws.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var row = rng.filter(String).length;

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['NEW', 'OPEN', 'COMPLETE', 'PENDING'], true).build();

  open_ws.getRange(row, 1).setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

Comment: How about `e.range.rowStart`? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: @Tanaike That worked and I see why it should work however e.rowStart did produce a number before. I must have been using `range` and didn't realize it when I moved my code.